# Automatically build shared fortran library in setup.py and link it to f2py

Tags: python, fortran, shared-libraries, distutils

I am looking for the best way to generate a `setup.py` file which build my package based on Fortran routines.

**Package/Module structure**

```
.
├── CHANGES.txt
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── PKG
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── xx.f90
│   │   ├── yy.f90
│   │   ├── gg.py
│   ├── dirA
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── ee.py
│   │   ├── bb.py
├── setup.py
```

**Manual compilation of Fortran's files**

In order to generate the Python wrapper and compile the Fortran files, I can do it using the following workflow (in the folder lib):

`gfortran -fPIC -Wall -fcheck=all --shared xx.f90 -o xx.o` [1]

and

`f2py -c -m yy yy.f90 xx.o`

The previous line insures the linking between the shared library `xx.o` and the library `yy.f90.

*Notice that `f2py -c -m xx xx.f90` does not work because of the use of some syntaxes which are not usable with f2py (use of allocatable arguments in subroutines...).*

**Current `setup.py` (not working)**

I use the `Extension` module of `numpy.distutils`:

```
import os
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
#
pkgs['PKG'] = 'PKG'
pkgs['PKG.lib'] = 'PKG/lib'
pkgs['PKG.dirA'] = 'PKG/dirA'
#
exts = list()
exts.append(
    Extension(name='PKG.lib.yy',
              sources=['PKG/lib/yy.f90','PKG/lib/xx.o'],
              extra_compile_args=['-g','--backtrace'],
              extra_link_args=[],
              f2py_options=['--debug-capi']))
    ###
    ### 
    setup(name = 'PKG',
          ext_modules = exts,
          packages = list(pkgs.keys()),
          package_dir = pkgs,
          include_package_data=True,
          zip_safe=False
          )
```

**Question**

Is there any way to integrate the building of the shared library in the `setup.py`? One solution could be to run manually the line [1] but if possible I want to avoid to use my own syntax in order to use the same gfortran compiler and options used by `f2py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution is to use `library`/`libraries` arguments in extension and setup:

```
import os
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
#
pkgs['PKG'] = 'PKG'
pkgs['PKG.lib'] = 'PKG/lib'
pkgs['PKG.dirA'] = 'PKG/dirA'
#
exts = list()
exts.append(
    Extension(name='PKG.lib.yy',
              sources=['PKG/lib/yy.f90'],
              extra_compile_args=['-g','--backtrace'],
              extra_link_args=[],
              libraries=['xx'],
              f2py_options=['--debug-capi']))
    ###
    ### 
    setup(name = 'PKG',
          ext_modules = exts,
          packages = list(pkgs.keys()),
          package_dir = pkgs,
          libraries=['xx',sources=['PKG/lib/xx.f90']],
          include_package_data=True,
          zip_safe=False
          )
```

Another solution using `Configuration`

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration

config = Configuration('PKG')
config.packages=['PKG','PKG.lib']
config.add_extension('lib.yy',
    sources=['PKG/lib/MeshField2D.f90'],
    libraries=['xx'])

config.add_library('xx',
    sources=['PKG/lib/xx.f90'])   

setup(**config.todict())
```